# How can I align 3 divs in the middle of the page?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need help to align 3 divs in the middle of the page. I managed them to be aligned horizontally but I can't put them in the middle. I tried but the middle one just go into the third one when I fill the div with something.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFfUw.jpg

Here's the HTML code(I'm using bootstrap):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="/pfp.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">Name: </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Age: </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="desc" class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id="middle" class="col">
        Colegiul National "Nicolae Titulescu"
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-indicators">
              <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
              <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
              <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="/cnntcarousel1.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="/cnntcarousel2.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="/cnntcarousel3.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img src="/pfp.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item">Name: </li>
                <li class="list-group-item">Age: </li>
            </ul>
            <div id="desc" class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
              <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is the CSS code I'm using:

```
.container {
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
left: auto;
font-family: Lemon Milk;
/*background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4)*/}
#middle {
text-align: center;
color: white;}
```

I'm using `position: absolute;` because I have a background image on the page body.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping them in a parent div and using margin left auto, margin right auto on said parent ?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and flexible way is using `flex`. Read more help [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)